# Unable to map namespaces to xmlns namespaces in xaml

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I'm following a tutorial on MVVM and am having some issues.

I created 4 folders which represent 4 different namespaces. In my `MainPage.xaml` I'm making a reference to these namespaces using the following code:

```
xmlns:viewModels="using:ViewModels"
xmlns:converters="using:Converters"
```

These properties are in the `Page` attributes.

Next, I need to use those using the following code:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <converters:ObjectExistsToVisible x:Key="ObjectExistsToVisible" />
</Page.Resources>


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView  x:Name="MainList" 
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Organization.People, Mode=OneWay}"  
          SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Organization.SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          MinWidth="250" Margin="5">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- The error is with x:DataType="" -->
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:PersonViewModel" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Add" Click="{x:Bind  Organization.Add}" Margin="5"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox 
          Text="{x:Bind Organization.SelectedPerson.Name, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=''}" 
          Margin="5" />
        <TextBox 
          Text="{x:Bind Organization.SelectedPerson.Age, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue='0'}" 
          Margin="5" />
        <Button Content="Delete" Click="{x:Bind Organization.Delete}" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The tutorial can be found at: [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/)

The problem is, I'm getting the following errors:

> The name "ObjectExistsToVisible" does not exist in the namespace "using:Converters"
>
> The name "PersonViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "using:ViewModels"

I'm pretty sure that they do exist.

As requested:

PersonViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Data;

namespace ViewModels
{
    public class PersonViewModel : NotificationBase<Person>
    {
        public PersonViewModel(Person person = null) : base(person) { }
        public String Name
        {
            get { return This.Name; }
            set { SetProperty(This.Name, value, () => This.Name = value); }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get { return This.Age; }
            set { SetProperty(This.Age, value, () => This.Age = value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're pretty sure they exist?  How did you verify?  Normally, your namespace would be `MuhApplicationName.SomeNamespace`.  Open up PersonViewModel.cs, copy everything from the top of the file down to the class definition (public class PersonViewModel...) and paste it into an [edit].

Comment: @Will Updated the post. I tried using `MyApplicationName.SomeNamespace` before, which didn't work. So I followed the tutorial letter by letter which also didn't work.

Comment: No, your namespace is correct.  If the errors are within the designer, make sure you clean and build the solution.  If it builds correctly and you don't get any runtime errors due to this namespace problem, it's just a problem with the editor.  False errors reported in the editor is a common problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @Will Yep, that fixed it! Will have to look out for that in the future. Thanks!

Comment: You can share details about how you fixed this in an answer and close this question out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a great comment from Will, the solution is as follows:

First, clean the solution via `Build > Clean Solution`.
Next, rebuild the solution via `Build > Rebuild Solution`.

This fixed the errors for me.